# Does HSTS inlcudeSubDomains directive include subdomains on all levels?

Tags: http, hsts, sub-domain

I asked this question on Stack Overflow, but thought its more relevant here.
Regarding the HSTS includeSubDomains directive. Does this include every subdomain underneath e.g. example.com. So abc.def.example.com is also included?

In the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7469#section-2.1.3):

```
The OPTIONAL "includeSubDomains" directive is a valueless directive
which, if present (i.e., it is "asserted"), signals the UA that the
HSTS Policy applies to this HSTS Host as well as any subdomains of
the host's domain name.
```

This states "any", can I take that to mean every subdomain, no matter what level, e.g. sub1.sub2.sub3.example.com and not just sub3.example.com?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this *should* apply to all subdomains (see [Steffen Ullrich's comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124272/does-hsts-inlcudesubdomains-directive-include-subdomains-on-all-levels/124278?noredirect=1#comment229093_124278) for caveat).

In `foo.bar.foobar`, `foo` is a subdomain of `bar.foobar`, and `bar` is a subdomain of `foobar`, so therefore `foo.bar.foobar` is an indirect subdomain of `foobar`.

Comment: That's the theory but according to [this unclosed bug for Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1202112) it is not the reality, at least with Firefox.

Comment: @SilverlightFox, I know this is old, but do we (you!) know if this has been completely solved for all browsers?

IOW, If I visit the `example.com` TLD and get back an HSTS header with `includeSubdomains`, will it apply to `foo.bar.isnt.this.cool.example.com`. What about if `cool.example.com` has an HSTS header without `includeSubdomains`?

Comment: @roryhewitt This should show you current browser support: https://caniuse.com/stricttransportsecurity Yes, it would apply to `foo.bar.isnt.this.cool.example.com`. I would expect that the overriding policy would apply for your next qeustion. That is, once `example.com` had been visited, then all subdomains would be forced to be HTTPS until `max-age` had expired (taken from the last visit to an HTTP resource on that domain by the browser). When it expires, then the policy on `cool.example.com` would apply if not expired, without including `foo.bar.isnt.this.cool.example.com`